# wx python on OSX crashes

Tags: python, macos

I have a simple program that allows the user to double click on a label and move it. It works perfectly on Windows and Linux, but crashes on OSX with variously:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

or sometimes

```
Bus error: 10
```

Can anyone help? The program follows:

```
import wx

class DoubleClick(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, title):
    super(DoubleClick, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
        size=(250, 200))

    self.mainSizer=wx.GridBagSizer()
    self.Available=['square','circle','cross','triangle']
    self.Used=[]

    self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
    self.Center()
    self.Show()
    self.DisplayShapes()       

  def RefreshSizerCell(self, item, row, column):
    oldItem=self.mainSizer.FindItemAtPosition((row, column))
    if (oldItem !=None) and oldItem.IsWindow():
      oldItem.GetWindow().Destroy()
      pass
    self.mainSizer.Add(item, pos=(row, column), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)
    self.Layout()
    self.Fit()

  def onAvailableDClick(self, e):
    if len(self.Available)>0:
      shape=self.GetShapeName(e)  
      self.Used.append(str(shape))
      self.Available.remove(shape)  
      self.DisplayShapes() 

  def onUsedDClick(self, e):
    if len(self.Used)>0:
      shape=self.GetShapeName(e)  
      self.Available.append(str(shape))
      self.Used.remove(shape)  
      self.DisplayShapes()  

  def DisplayShapes(self):
    availableSizer=ShapeDisplay(self, self.Available, self.onAvailableDClick)
    self.RefreshSizerCell(availableSizer,0,0) 
    usedSizer=ShapeDisplay(self, self.Used, self.onUsedDClick)
    self.RefreshSizerCell(usedSizer,1,0)

  def GetShapeName(self, event):
    imgCtrl=event.GetEventObject()
    shape=imgCtrl.GetName()
    return shape

class ShapeDisplay(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, shapeList, bindTo):
      wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)

      shapeSizer=wx.GridBagSizer()
      shapePos=0
      for ii in range(0, len(shapeList)):
        shape=shapeList[ii]   
        lblShape=wx.StaticText(self, label=shape, name=shape)
        lblShape.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, bindTo)
        shapeSizer.Add(lblShape, pos=(0,shapePos), flag=wx.LEFT, border=5)
        shapePos+=1 
      self.SetSizer(shapeSizer) 


if __name__ == '__main__':

  myApp = wx.App()
  DoubleClick(None, title='Double click')
  myApp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can no one help me with this? Pleeeeease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

In the method RefreshSizerCell replace the line:

```
  oldItem.GetWindow().Destroy()
```

with

```
  oldItem.GetWindow().Hide()
  self.mainSizer.Detach(oldItem.GetWindow())
```

Not sure why one method works on Linux/Windows and not on OSX, while the other works on all 3